# SSH to multiple servers with username and password

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I want to do SSH with username and password to multiple servers 
need to know option to put username password in below script

```
for HOST in $(cat ping.txt ) ; do ssh $HOST "ping -c 10  google.com" ; done
```

Comment: Can easy reach with **expect**

Comment: does your server's have same login password? If yes, then make use of sshpass.

Comment: Can't use expect here..Looking for other solution

Comment: Client dependency can't download any new file need to work with existing infra

Comment: You cannot do it with just basic tools. `ssh` only accepts passwords typed on a terminal. You need to use something like `sshpass` (recommended) or expect (if you like pain).

Comment: Time to learn how to setup ssh private & public keys. Read any ssh tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You can use sshpass, but better to use [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/).
Example of sshpass usage:

```
# vim server.list
192.168.0.100
192.168.0.101

# apt-get install sshpass
$ vim script.sh
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
    echo "running $line"
    SSHPASS=PASSWORD sshpass -e ssh-copy-id USERNAME@"$line" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"
done < "server.list"
```

Run script:

```
$ sh script.sh
running 192.168.0.100
...
Number of key(s) added: 1
running 192.168.0.101
...
Number of key(s) added: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `expect`,

```
#script.sh    
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
    username=user
    password=pass
    for HOST in $(cat $1)
            do
                    echo "ssh $username@$HOST"
                    expect "Password:"
                    send "$pass\r"
            done

file.txt
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
```

**bash script.sh file.txt**

Comment: I required not to use expect. Suggest wayout with shell script with additional addon download.